# Storage requirements for booting Windows 10 on a Mac running OS X Yosemite

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, boot-camp, refit

I have read a few articles that state that, for booting Windows 10 (using either Boot Camp or rEFIt/rEFInd) on a Mac, you should have at least 30GiB free of disk space, and at least a 16-20GiB flash drive. Is this accurate? Also, if I downloaded a program on Windows, would it save to the flash drive or to my computer?

Comment: Do you intend to upgrade  or do a clean install? Do you have a Product Key?

Comment: I intend to do a clean install, and yes, I do have the product key.